# Why are Proofs of God dismissed as 'philosophical' and not considered 'theological"... unfit for Christianity SE?

Tags: discussion

Don't proofs of God apply to Systematic Theology doctrines? (See the first couple chapters on "Theology Proper" in any Systematic Theology textbook.)

Would not users benefit from Proofs of God (Dismantling Atheism) by Questions and Answers on Christianity SE?  Examples of closed questions:

- [Does Modern Science come to the aid of Christianity's Doctrine of Creation, exposing a flaw in Atheism's plank of "No Cause"?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/94876/does-modern-science-come-to-the-aid-of-christianitys-doctrine-of-creation-expo)
- [Is there a way to prove the God of the Bible?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5923/is-there-a-way-to-prove-the-god-of-the-bible)

Have not major **theologians** dealt with 'proofs of God' as part of their important and legitimate studies?

And are you not unaware that Theistic questions (Scrutinizing atheism) are cruelly, unfairly treated with intolerance and mocking on Philosophy SE? They also consider such as "off-topic" and dismiss them as "pushing one's personal philosophy."

Must God, then, just go to the streets and manifest Himself to the *hoi polloi*, outside of academia?

Answer (score 1):

Systematic theology will always be subject to controversy in a way that dogmatic theology is not.  If you want clarification of a certain scholars ideas, that's OK. If you want to throw out a question and have them to fight it out, that's not - as answers go they're literally no different than having multiple denominations vie over infant baptism.

If you want to start another site about systematic theology, Area 51 is always an option.  I will definitely help provide the powers that be an argument or two for why systematic theology is not the same as Christianity.

Comment: Still learning about how Catholics use the term "systematic theology". In Protestant circles (at past 100 years),  "systematic theology" simply refers to systematic presentation of theology, and yes, distinguished from "dogmatic theology" in that the latter carries official weight / ecclesiastical sanction (see *GotQuestons* [article about the differences](https://www.gotquestions.org/dogmatic-theology.html)). I think *Summa Theologica* is an ex. of "systematic theology". Asking Q about the construction and the content of a "systematic theology" should be on topic, provided it's **objective**.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to think that as long as we are discussing proofs of God that have been advocated by a relatively prominent Christian theologian, it should be on topic.  For example, one can ask a question on Aquinas's cosmological argument for God.

But soliciting **strategies** on how to "dismantle atheism" borders on opinion-based.  Can you edit the Q with an example question that has been closed?  I can probably suggest on tweaking the question so it can be used to "dismantle atheism" while making it *still* fit for C.SE.

Comment: @GratefulDiscipleHere are two examples of "closure" on Christianity SE: one by me, and another by someone else.  (1)  #94876 "Does modern science come to the aid of Christianity's Doctrine of Creation, exposing a flaw in Atheism's plank of 'No Cause'"? (closed)  (2) #5923 " Is there a way to prove the God of the Bible?" (closed)

Comment: @raygrant Thanks.  I hope you don't mind my adding those 2 examples to the OP.  I'll try to revise my answer in the coming week (currently busy) with suggestions to make the Q on topic again.  Feel free to add more examples to the OP.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple-Grateful user!

Answer (score -2):

The world by wisdom knew not God.

Only the coming of God manifest in flesh (in the Person of the Son of God, incarnate) has brought the true knowledge of God.

The question above does not even mention Christ, and nor do the convoluted philosophical arguments referred to.

Therefore, such content belongs on a site other than that named 'Christianity'.

Nowhere in scripture do we see such arguments or discussions.

Because the bible is *God's way* of expressing himself . . . . .

. . . .  through Jesus Christ, the only begotten of the Father.

Comment: Romans 1:21-32 has regularly been cited for the world's knowledge of God, despite incomplete without OT and Christ.  Thus philosophers' argument for God is regularly covered in Systematic Theology books (OP assertion is correct) as a **Preamble to Faith**, to establish common ground with the World in preparation for the Gospel.  Faith completes Reason, NOT replaces Reason.  Complete theology INCLUDES reason, and thus Preamble questions belong in C.SE.  Of course, we need guidelines on how to properly including **Christian** philosophy Q&A in C.SE, which is what OP is implying.

Comment: @NigelSince "the heavens declare the glory of God..." Natural Theology has a lot to say about God.  Paul appealed to this evidence in Romans 1-2, and Acts 17 (at Athens).   Of course, it is only partial revelation (General Revelation), and our understanding is completed by the Incarnation of Jesus who filled in the details (Special Revelation, Hebrews 1:1-2).  Notice:  NATURAL THEOLOGY (Gen. Rev.)--->HISTORICAL THEOLOGY (Exodus to Jesus)--->SYSTEMATIC THEOLOGY (N.T. theology). There are no "gaps" in the process of coming to faith; it is an informed faith that enhances a life of trust in God.